# render html showing extra double quotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this javascript which making an html

```
var html = "<input type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' value='Ok'" +
                                    "onclick='TaskFinishedRequestMode(" + data[i].TaskFinishedRequest + "," + data[i].EmpTaskAssignCompletionId + "," + data[i].RequestById + "," + data[i].TeamLead + ", \'" + data[i].Employee_Name + "\' , \'" + data[i].ProjectName + "\' )'/>" ;
```

The problem is that it is rendering html like this with line break

[image]

Therefore i am getting this error as i press the button

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token**

Update:

The data is string in data[i].Employee_Name  , data[i].ProjectName while rest is integer.

Comment: If you are going to pass in strings inline as an argument you need to surround them with single or double quotes.  Just like you would when passing them normally in pure js logic.

Comment: how to do that i have used &quot;

Comment: You can use `\"` to escape a double quote at the start and end of the strings.

Comment: Need more info... What are you using to parse this string into HTML? What is contained in these variables? Do any of them contain `\n` for some reason? Also, it would probably be cleaner to create your element without the `onclick`, and then attach a click listener to it with `element.addEventListener('click', callbackFunction)` instead of building up function parameters as a string.

Comment: @philraj The data is string in data[i].Employee_Name , data[i].ProjectName while rest is integer

Comment: When? i was just updating my question

Comment: @philraj wait i am still updating

Comment: Are you creating the HTML string at JavaScript to append to `document`?

Comment: @philraj please see update question

Comment: @Taplar please see updated question

Comment: @guest271314 i am using jquery html() function to add my html string

Comment: If you are using jQuery why do you attach event using global event attribute `onclick`?

Comment: After testing it out, you may actually have to convert the \n to \\n as it appears the new lines in the markup will actually make js error.

Comment: Try this fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/0juhsq9x/

Answer (score 1):

I would **strongly** suggest you make your life easier by not creating the `onclick` attribute with your string. It's forcing you to keep track of opening and closing quotations in a way that's just unnecessary.

You could create your HTML first:

```js
var htmlString = "<input type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' value='Ok'/>";
$('#container').html(htmlString);
```

Then, target your new input element and add your click listener:

```js
$('#container > input').on('click', function (event) {
  TaskFinishedRequestMode(
    data[i].TaskFinishedRequest,
    data[i].EmpTaskAssignCompletionId,
    data[i].RequestById,
    data[i].TeamLead,
    data[i].Employee_Name,
    data[i].ProjectName
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure js, using object creation over string creation

```js
function TaskFinishedRequestMode () {
  console.log( arguments );
}

var data = [{
  TaskFinishedRequest: 1234,
  EmpTaskAssignCompletionId: 5678,
  RequestById: 9101112,
  TeamLead: "ThaPope",
  Employee_Name: `Mark
Wal

Berg (sp)`,
  ProjectName: `Crazy






New Lines`
}];
var i = 0;
var input = document.createElement( 'input' );

input.type = 'button';
input.classList.add('btn');
input.classList.add( 'btn-sm');
input.classList.add('btn-primary');
input.value = 'Ok';
input.onclick = function() {
  TaskFinishedRequestMode(
    data[i].TaskFinishedRequest,
    data[i].EmpTaskAssignCompletionId,
    data[i].RequestById,
    data[i].TeamLead,
    data[i].Employee_Name,
    data[i].ProjectName
  );
};

document.body.appendChild(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly you can use `jQuery(html, attributes)` to avoid using global event handler attributes.

Within loop you can define the expected parameters as elements of an array, use rest element at `TaskFinishRequestMode` function parameter, `Function.prototype.apply()` to pass the array of expected function parameters.

```js
var data = [{
  TaskFinishedRequest: 1,
  EmpTaskAssignCompletionId: 2,
  RequestById: 3,
  TeamLead: 4,
  Employee_Name: 5,
  ProjectName: 6
}];

function TaskFinishRequestMode(...args) {
  console.log(args); // `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`
}

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  var args = [
    data[i].TaskFinishedRequest,
    data[i].EmpTaskAssignCompletionId,
    data[i].RequestById,
    data[i].TeamLead,
    data[i].Employee_Name,
    data[i].ProjectName
  ];

  var html = $("<input>", {
    "type": "button",
    "class": "btn btn-sm btn-primary",
    "value": "Ok",
    "on": {
      "click": function() {
        // pass `args` array as parameter to `TaskFinishRequestMode`
        TaskFinishRequestMode.apply(null, args);
      }
    }
  });
  $("body").append(html)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var html = "<input type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' value='Ok' " + 
                "onclick='TaskFinishedRequestMode(" + 
                    data[i].TaskFinishedRequest + ", " + 
                    data[i].EmpTaskAssignCompletionId + ", " + 
                    data[i].RequestById + ", " + 
                    data[i].TeamLead + ", \"" + 
                    data[i].Employee_Name + "\", \"" + 
                    data[i].ProjectName + "\")' />";
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in `var html = " ... onclick='TaskFinishedRequestMode(\" ... )'"`. This gets read as `html = " ... onclick='TaskFinishedRequestMode(\"`, with the rest of the data throwing a syntax error.

Considering you're using double-quotes for your main string declaration, and single-quotes for your inner `onclick`, you need to **escape** all of the double-quotes contained within the `onclick` by prepending a backslash (`\"`) as follows:

```js
var html = "<input type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' value='Ok'  onclick='TaskFinishedRequestMode(\" + data[i].TaskFinishedRequest + \",\" + data[i].EmpTaskAssignCompletionId + \",\" + data[i].RequestById + \",\" + data[i].TeamLead + \", &quot;\" + data[i].Employee_Name + \"&quot; , &quot; \" + data[i].ProjectName + \" &quot; )'/>";
document.write(html);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: You escaped some " but you're missing the real " that terminate the strings before concating the variables.

Comment: @Taplar -- Which one? I've escaped every double-quote apart from the very start and very last one of `var html = " "` as far as I'm aware.

Comment: these are coming as it is in function data[i].TaskFinishedRequest  ......

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/basv8rmv/  literal string.  as is it does not try to use any variables.  Vs https://jsfiddle.net/basv8rmv/1/ ( i only change a few of them ) which will try to use the variables.